# Metro UI C#: How do you make a form within a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, java-metro-framework, metro-ui-css

I want to know how to open different forms with a single main parent form in `Metro Framework UI` similar to a `Modern POS System`. As far as I know, I haven't found anything remotely close to that in the internet and I'm also having trouble trying to figure it out in Metro. Also I'm not talking about `MDI Forms`

Here's an example: (not in Metro)
[Modern POS Design (watch first few seconds of the vid)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLfzH4xOVqo)

I'm talking about a dashboard type of UI where you open different modules using buttons on the left side of the Main form and the modules are opened as a child form in the Main form.

Comment: Why not hire them to do it?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I watched the first few seconds as you suggested, and it was just some fancy intro

Answer (score 0):

It has so many bugs when it comes to that kind of procedure. You can just use a simple form rather that MetroForm because MetroForm creates a somewhat black form on your screen when calling as child form. I don't know if it just in my application but it is really annoying.

You can just add your other forms to a panel at your main form.

There are many tutorials on how to do this but i will give you an example.
I created a method something like this in my utilclass:

```
public static Form NewForm(Form myForm, Panel myPanel)
    {
        myForm.TopLevel = false;
        myForm.AutoScroll = true;
        myForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        myPanel.Controls.Clear();
        myPanel.Controls.Add(myForm);

        myForm.Show();
        return myForm;
    }
```

then calling from Main form to a panel:

```
Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
UtilClass.NewForm(myForm2 , [YourMainFormPanel]);
```

I know this code is not the best approach but I'm just giving you ideas.